# kubernetes на Hetzner vServer

Tags: nat, kubernetes

Развернут кластер kubernetes на vServer'ах.

Каждый vServer имеет серый адрес 172.31.1.100. У хостера подход 1:1 nat - 
[ссылка на hetzner](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/VServer/ru#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.83_.D0.B2.D0.B8.D1.80.D1.82.D1.83.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.88.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.B5.D1.82_IP_172.31.1.100.3F)

etcd, apiserver слушают externalIP

podNetwork на нодах не видят друг друга и нет резолва

Пингую сам себя:

```
kube@kube1:~$ ping 10.244.0.0
PING 10.244.0.0 (10.244.0.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.244.0.0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.0.0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
^C
--- 10.244.0.0 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1027ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.039/0.052/0.065/0.013 ms
```

Пингую podNetwork, расположенную на другой ноде:

```
kube@kube1:~$ ping 10.244.1.0
PING 10.244.1.0 (10.244.1.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.244.1.0 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12274ms
```

Пинг с pod'a в мир:

```
kube@kube1:~$ kubectl exec dnsutils -- ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=3.71 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=6.49 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=3.73 ms
^C
```

Резолв с pod'a:

```
kube@kube1:~$ kubectl exec dnsutils -- nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

Состояние:

```
kube@kube1:~$ kubectl get no
NAME         STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
kube1.htzn   Ready     master    2d        v1.8.4
kube3.htzn   Ready     <none>    2d        v1.8.4
kube4.htzn   Ready     <none>    2d        v1.8.4

kube@kubectl get services -n kube-system
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   2d

kube@kubectl get po -n kube-system
kube-apiserver-kube1.htzn            1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube1.htzn
kube-controller-manager-kube1.htzn   1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube1.htzn
kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-4c84v            3/3       Running   0          2d        10.244.2.6       kube4.htzn
kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-4xbbr            3/3       Running   0          2d        10.244.1.10      kube3.htzn
kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-j25wx            3/3       Running   0          2d        10.244.1.9       kube3.htzn
kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-l4q9d            3/3       Running   0          2d        10.244.0.10      kube1.htzn
kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-lh8rc            3/3       Running   0          2d        10.244.2.4       kube4.htzn
kube-flannel-ds-8wdcg                1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube4.htzn
kube-flannel-ds-9zj22                1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube1.htzn
kube-flannel-ds-m48lq                1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube3.htzn
kube-proxy-22lpv                     1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube4.htzn
kube-proxy-g5gcq                     1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube1.htzn
kube-proxy-ll96w                     1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube3.htzn
kube-scheduler-kube1.htzn            1/1       Running   0          2d        externalIP   kube1.htzn
```

ifconfig на мастере:

```
br-37317408aabe: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:00:96:fc:f1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0 

cni0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::68b3:f8ff:fec7:f2a5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:58:0a:f4:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 730314  bytes 171524562 (163.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 778142  bytes 168028178 (160.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::42:8aff:fe57:275a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:8a:57:27:5a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 179202  bytes 23207264 (22.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 144645  bytes 65400826 (62.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.1.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.31.1.255
        inet6 2a01:4f8:c0c:3c00::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::5054:a2ff:fe02:264a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:a2:02:26:4a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22655506  bytes 6814574498 (6.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22836130  bytes 7824566265 (7.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

flannel.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.0.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::a85d:92ff:fed1:ec2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether aa:5d:92:d1:0e:c2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1960 (1.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 1960 (1.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 4 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3184471  bytes 424875074 (405.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3184471  bytes 424875074 (405.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth3d3e856: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9450:8aff:fe39:db80  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 96:50:8a:39:db:80  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 179202  bytes 25716092 (24.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 144649  bytes 65401186 (62.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth520581d9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::5019:8aff:fe71:5e02  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:19:8a:71:5e:02  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 725841  bytes 180660769 (172.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 773371  bytes 166986212 (159.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ip r:

```
default via 172.31.1.1 dev ens3
10.244.0.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.0.1
10.244.1.0/24 via 10.244.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
10.244.2.0/24 via 10.244.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-37317408aabe proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown
172.31.1.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.1.100
```

iptables -t nat -L -n:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes service portals */
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes service portals */
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-POSTROUTING  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes postrouting rules */
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  10.244.0.0/16        10.244.0.0/16
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.244.0.0/16       !224.0.0.0/4
RETURN     all  -- !10.244.0.0/16        10.244.0.0/24
MASQUERADE  all  -- !10.244.0.0/16        10.244.0.0/16

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain KUBE-MARK-DROP (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK or 0x8000

Chain KUBE-MARK-MASQ (14 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK or 0x4000

Chain KUBE-NODEPORTS (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-POSTROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000

Chain KUBE-SEP-2STLUSOBI3YCA5AH (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  94.130.110.182       0.0.0.0/0            /* default/kubernetes:https */
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* default/kubernetes:https */ recent: SET name: KUBE-SEP-2STLUSOBI3YCA5AH side: source mask: 255.255.255.255 tcp to:94.130.110.182:6443

Chain KUBE-SEP-BGFZBX5GRCLSKMIC (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.2.4           0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp to:10.244.2.4:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-DFSYEE766Q4KZDEE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.2.6           0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp to:10.244.2.6:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-E62IRM24GBWVMUE5 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.1.10          0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp to:10.244.1.10:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-HPQF756YQTNK43WA (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.1.9           0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp to:10.244.1.9:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-NWYX6ZRA4HKJWFJ6 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.1.9           0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ udp to:10.244.1.9:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-OP4AXEAS4OXHBEQX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.0.10          0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp to:10.244.0.10:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-QZ2RMBQRVUNY2HKV (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.1.10          0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ udp to:10.244.1.10:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-R7EMXN5TTQQVP4UW (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.0.10          0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ udp to:10.244.0.10:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-RJHMR3QLYGJVBWVL (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.2.4           0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ udp to:10.244.2.4:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-XABH6FUURDMVT5Y2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.2.6           0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ udp to:10.244.2.6:53

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  tcp  -- !10.244.0.0/16        10.96.0.1            /* default/kubernetes:https cluster IP */ tcp dpt:443
KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.1            /* default/kubernetes:https cluster IP */ tcp dpt:443
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  udp  -- !10.244.0.0/16        10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP */ udp dpt:53
KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP */ udp dpt:53
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  tcp  -- !10.244.0.0/16        10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP */ tcp dpt:53
KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP */ tcp dpt:53
KUBE-NODEPORTS  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes service nodeports; NOTE: this must be the last rule in this chain */ ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SEP-OP4AXEAS4OXHBEQX  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ statistic mode random probability 0.20000000019
KUBE-SEP-E62IRM24GBWVMUE5  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ statistic mode random probability 0.25000000000
KUBE-SEP-HPQF756YQTNK43WA  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ statistic mode random probability 0.33332999982
KUBE-SEP-BGFZBX5GRCLSKMIC  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ statistic mode random probability 0.50000000000
KUBE-SEP-DFSYEE766Q4KZDEE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */

Chain KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SEP-2STLUSOBI3YCA5AH  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* default/kubernetes:https */ recent: CHECK seconds: 10800 reap name: KUBE-SEP-2STLUSOBI3YCA5AH side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
KUBE-SEP-2STLUSOBI3YCA5AH  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* default/kubernetes:https */

Chain KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SEP-R7EMXN5TTQQVP4UW  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ statistic mode random probability 0.20000000019
KUBE-SEP-QZ2RMBQRVUNY2HKV  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ statistic mode random probability 0.25000000000
KUBE-SEP-NWYX6ZRA4HKJWFJ6  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ statistic mode random probability 0.33332999982
KUBE-SEP-RJHMR3QLYGJVBWVL  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ statistic mode random probability 0.50000000000
KUBE-SEP-XABH6FUURDMVT5Y2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */
```

Answer (score 0):

Была подобная фигня на хестнере когда виртуалка была в в датацентре финляндии а другая в другом датацентре. При чем это только у финских виртуалок такое с сетью бывает и не у каждой.

Удали виртуалку и добавь ноду по новой в кластер

и личше используй сетку calico вместо flannel